# CSS3 background-size property doesn't works in IE8

Tags: css, internet-explorer, internet-explorer-8

i used this Hack in my site, but still i could not make around the background-size issue, can anyone help me on this issue?

```
filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.AlphaImageLoader( src='../img/logo_sm.png', sizingMethod='scale'); 
-ms-filter: "progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.AlphaImageLoader( src='../img/logo_sm.png', sizingMethod='scale')";
```

My code:

```
.dropdown-menu {
background-image: url(../pics/Responsive/dropdown-bg.png);
background-size: 100% auto;
background-position: top left;
background-repeat: no-repeat;
background-color: transparent;
top: 100%;
left: 10%;
position: absolute;
text-align: center;
border: 0;
box-shadow: none;
width: 1048px !important;
float: none !important;
margin: 0 auto !important;
top: 56px !important;
min-height: 200px!important;
border: 0 none !important;
padding: 10px 6% 0;
filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.AlphaImageLoader(src='../pics/Responsive/dropdown-bg.png',sizingMethod='scale');
-ms-filter: "progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.AlphaImageLoader(src='../pics/Responsive/dropdown-bg.png',sizingMethod='scale')";
```

}

Comment: What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: @Husman thx for reply. i just want to cover my dropdown with my background image